# Exposing CQ content as a restful webservice

Tags: aem, restful-url, jcr

We are facing a scenario where we need to to expose our CQ content (as XML or JSON) to serve as an integration point. 
Any pointers to achieve this a would be helpful.

San

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - "any pointers" is not a specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

everything is content! 
you can get json-output of every node simply but you probably want to implement a custom servlet to server specific requirements i guess.
try this:

http://192.168.56.56:4503/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men/coats.infinity.json
http://192.168.56.56:4503/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men/coats.3.json

Take a look at the [sling docs](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) and learn how sling is resolving resources (sling cheat sheet)

Comment: Is it possible to create a custom web service with in CQ (following the rest principles) to expose content for external users?

Answer (score 1):

Content in AEM can be made available to end users in several ways, like html page, PDF, xml, json.

Sitemap.xml is one of similar content. You can create custom restful APIs to read content from JCR repository, put them in required format (xml/json or some other) and expose it to end users. As @chrysler said, take a look at [sling docs](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) for more learning.

Answer (score 1):

Write a selector jsp(json.html.jsp) in your component and call your service method that will return the JSON based on your need.

So your request URL with selector say ../home.json.html will return the desired json output.

Note : Make sure when you don't override cq default json calls. Eg: when your request URL is like ../home.json and your selector jsp is json.jsp , this will override the out of box json call and you will find authoring dialog working not expected.